# SwiftUI / Firestore Displaying posts from users you follow / favorite

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app that has users and trainers. Trainers can post workouts for users to see. A user has the ability to favorite a trainer profile as well. I am trying to make the home feed only show workouts from trainers that have been favorited by the user.

**The firestore structure is like this:**

COLLECTIONS, DOCUMENTS IN COLLECTION, FIELDS WITHIN THOSE DOCUMENTS, OR SUBCOLLECTIONS

1. users

   a. user ID with all the fields nested (name, email, id, etc...)

   b. (subcollection) favorited-trainers (trainer ID)
2. trainers

   a. trainer ID with all the fields nested (name, email, id, etc...)

   b. (subcollection) favorites-users (user ID)
3. workouts

   a. workout ID with all the fields nested (title, trainer id, workout id, etc...)

**Function to favorite a trainer (adds to user and trainer subcollections):**

```
func favorite() {
    guard let trainerUid = trainer.id else { return }
    guard let currentUid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else { return }
    
    COLLECTION_USERS.document(currentUid).collection("favorited-trainers").document(trainerUid).setData([:])
    COLLECTION_TRAINERS.document(trainerUid).collection("favorites-users").document(currentUid).setData([:])
    self.trainer.isFavorited = true

}
```

**Current home page display just shows you all workouts in the app with this function:**

```
func fetchAllWorkouts() {
    COLLECTION_WORKOUTS.order(by: "timestamp", descending: true).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ in
        guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
        self.workouts = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Workout.self) })
    }
}
```

Is there anyway when I favorite a trainer account, I can go and search through the workouts, fetch all workouts that have that trainers ID and then add them to a new sub collection in the users collection called "user-feed" and put those workout IDs in it?

**EDIT:** I was thinking along the lines of a function like this to retrieve workouts from the trainer profile I am on and then setting the data in the users feed collection:

```
func addWorkoutsToFeed(){
    guard let trainerUid = trainer.id else { return }
    guard let currentUid = AuthViewModel.shared.userSession?.uid else { return }
    
    COLLECTION_WORKOUTS.whereField("ownerUid", isEqualTo: trainerUid).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ in
        guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
        let workouts = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Workout.self) })
        
        workouts.forEach { id in
            COLLECTION_USERS.document(currentUid).collection("user-feed").document(workouts).setData([:])
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Obviously this is failing because I do not think you can do this with set data by adding multiple documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do a for loop on favorite trainers and query on workouts with their ids.

```
var workouts : [Workout] = []

for trainer in favTrainer {
   fetchTrainerWorkouts(withId : trainer.Uid){ workouts in
      self.workouts += workouts
   }
}
```

fetchTrainerWorkouts:

```
func fetchTrainerWorkouts(withId trainerId: String , compilation : @escaping : ([Workout])->Void){
   WORKOUT_COLLECTION.whereField("TrainerUid" , isEqualTo:trainerId).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, _ in 
       guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
       let workouts = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Workout.self) })
       compilation(workouts)
   }
}
```

then in each snapshot, add workouts to your workouts array.

Comment: I made an edit to my original question with a function that I was thinking of trying. Would I not be able to do something along the lines of that?